# Reverse Geocode and Change the dropped pin in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapitem

What is the approach for this situation?

This will be my first time to do this problem.

There will be a user defined query(e.g. State, City) and then there will be a dropped pin on the query location. Then after that, user is able to move the pin from the initial dropped pin.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be to create a Strong object of [CLGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/index.html) so you can always reference the same object at anytime.

When a users drops the pin i assume you will be making a reverse geo code request with `reverseGeocodeLocation` method. At this point check to see if a request is in progress, if so use the `cancelGeocode` method to terminate the request and then set a new request with your new coordinate